# How to echo a substring from the output of a pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe, string

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428580/3414529) how to extract a substring in bash, but I'm lost as to how to apply this after a pipe. For instance:

```
some func | echo ${string:12:5}
```

How do I assign the output of `some func` to the variable `string`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${string:offset:length}` is a parameter expansion operator that expands to range of characters in the `$string` variable.

To get a range of *bytes* from the input (and that would then also apply to single-byte characters), you can use:

```
func | tail -c +12 | head -c 5
```

to get 5 bytes starting with  the 12th one (1-based offsets). The `-c` option to `head` is not standard but pretty common.

Note that `func` may be killed sometime after it has output its 16th byte, as `head` will exit after having output those 5 bytes, and `tail` would be killed if it tries to write more data after that, which would ripple to `func`.

You can also do:

```
func | dd bs=1 skip=11 count=5 2> /dev/null
```

`2> /dev/null` is to avoid the status message at the end. That suppresses all errors though. With GNU `dd`, you can replace it with `status=none` to only suppress the status.

For large values of `length`, that would be less efficient as it reads one byte at a time. With GNU `dd` again, you can avoid that by doing:

```
func | dd iflag=count_bytes,skip_bytes,fullblock skip=11 bs=64k count=5M status=none
```

Which would do as many reads of up to 64KiB each to get 5MiB bytes of data.

Now for those offset and length to be expressed in characters (single or multi-byte) instead of byte, that becomes more complicated.

An option is to store the whole output in a variable and use the `${var:offset:length}` operator [as others have shown](/a/443246). Though that means storing the whole output in memory. Using `var=$(func)` also means that the trailing newline characters are discarded.

Another option is to use `bash`'s `read -N` which does read a given number of *characters*:

```
func | {
  IFS= read -rN 11 discarded
  IFS= read -rN 5 data
  printf '%s\n' "$data"
}
```

Or with `perl` (slightly more efficient for large data):

```
func | perl -Mopen=locale -sne '
  BEGIN{$total = $o + $n; $/ = \$total}
  print substr($_, $o); exit' -- -o=10000 -n=5000000
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Answer

If you only wish to extract the output from `some_func`, you don't need to store it in a variable, you can just send the output to `cut` which will extract the requested characters:

```
some_func | cut -c 12-16
```

#### Explanation

`cut` Will take the `stdin` and extract the requested range based on specified options.

`-c` Means that the range is specified in characters.

`12-16` Range in which characters start with index `1`, not `0`.
Therefore, this will take characters at position `12`,`13`,`14`,`15` and `16`.

As [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) remainded me, note that this will work for each line of input, not just the first line.

Comment: Note that it gives the 12th to 16th characters (bytes with some implementation) of **each line** of the input, not of the input as a whole.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, maybe i should've noted that from the beginning. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
string="$(func)"
echo "${string:12:5}"
```